# On Android 4.2.2, how do I use ADT-Eclipse to browse the file system (with debugging enabled)?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-debugging

I have "Android debugging" enabled on this phone.  When I was running Android 4.0.4 and connected to my computer running ADT-Eclipse, I believe there was a tab under DDMS perspective for browsing the file system.  Assuming my memory serves me correct, is there some additional setting I need to enable for this to work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was (and still is) such a tab. It's called **File Explorer**, and by default it shows up in the same part of the screen as the **Threads** and **Heap** views. If you've hidden it in the past, you can show it again from the **Window** menu → **Show view**, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. (Thanks to Edgard Leal for suggesting the keyboard shortcut.)

Comment: What a rookie (me)!   It was simply hidden.. sheesh

Comment: Use ctrl+3 to find windows or commands:
ctrl+3 -> file expl .
Will show the window

Comment: @EdgardLeal Thanks for that tip! I've added it to the answer.